# Need to confirm what wikitude image recognition sample exactly does

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, wikitude, wikitude-sdk

I am testing [Wikitude sample](https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-sdk-samples/tree/master/01_ImageRecognition_1_ImageOnTarget) in Cordova based application. I am able to run it on my android Moto g4+ device , however I am not sure what exactly "01_ImageRecognition_1_ImageOnTarget" sample is doing.

In mycase, the app is launched , I have added a button on click of which, I initialize the wikitude, here is the source code:

```js
 // Url/Path to the augmented reality experience you would like to load
                self.arExperienceUrl = "www/wikitudesample/01_ImageRecognition_1_ImageOnTarget/index.html";
                // The features your augmented reality experience requires, only define the ones you really need
                self.requiredFeatures = ["image_tracking"];
                // Represents the device capability of launching augmented reality experiences with specific features
                self.isDeviceSupported = false;
                // Additional startup settings, for now the only setting available is camera_position (back|front)
                self.startupConfiguration = {
                    "camera_position": "back",
                    "camera_resolution": "auto"
                };
                // Application Constructor
                self.initialiseWikitude = function () {
                    console.log("wikitude: initialize");
                    self.wikitudePlugin = cordova.require("com.wikitude.phonegap.WikitudePlugin.WikitudePlugin");
                    console.log("after require");
                    self.wikitudePlugin.isDeviceSupported(self.onDeviceSupported, self.onDeviceNotSupported, self.requiredFeatures);
                };

                // Callback if the device supports all required features
                self.onDeviceSupported = function () {
                    console.log("wikitude: onDeviceSupported");



                    self.wikitudePlugin.loadARchitectWorld(
                            self.onARExperienceLoadedSuccessful,
                            self.onARExperienceLoadError,
                            self.arExperienceUrl,
                            self.requiredFeatures,
                            self.startupConfiguration
                            );

                };
                // Callback if the device does not support all required features
                self.onDeviceNotSupported = function (errorMessage) {
                    alert(errorMessage);
                    console.log("wikitude: onDeviceNotSupported");
                };
                // Callback if your AR experience loaded successful
                self.onARExperienceLoadedSuccessful = function (loadedURL) {
                    /* Respond to successful augmented reality experience loading if you need to */
                    console.log("wikitude: onARExperienceLoadedSuccessful");
                };
```

On launch of app, I invoke above code on click of button. On clicking the button everything successfully works (based on console logs). However what exactly this sample is doing?
[image]

**If possible can someone post video recording of this sample?**

Comment: This sample is showing a surfboard augmentation if you scan the surfer magazine page. https://youtu.be/OzehJ-fq-h4?t=21s shows the a more advanced image recognition sample, the only augmentation in the 01_ImageRecognition_1_ImageOnTarget sample is the surfbord. You can find the target images to test it here: https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/targetimages.html#target-images

Comment: @Alex Thanks so much, what I was missing was pointing to the right picture!!! I pointed to picture (https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/targetimages.html#target-images) and it worked as shown in youtube. THANKS!